# App.config readability for large string values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

I have various keys in `appSettings`, and each of them have a long string which contains values like these:

```
<add key="rightsTable" value="{LibraryNames='xxx',Folders='xxx',UserNames='xxx',RoleDefinitionNames='xxx'} {LibraryNames='yyy',Folders='yyy',UserNames='yyy',RoleDefinitionNames='yyy'} {LibraryNames='zzz',Folders='zzz',UserNames='zzz',RoleDefinitionNames='zzz'}" />
```

Now, in the App.config, I rearrange the string like this for readability:

```
<add key="rightsTable" 
     value=
     " 
{LibraryNames='xxx',Folders='xxx',UserNames='xxx',RoleDefinitionNames='xxx'}
{LibraryNames='yyy',Folders='yyy',UserNames='yyy',RoleDefinitionNames='yyy'}
{LibraryNames='zzz',Folders='zzz',UserNames='zzz',RoleDefinitionNames='zzz'}
     "
/>
```

However, whenever I publish the project, the resulting App.config is transformed to this:

```
 <add key="rightsTable" value="&#xD;&#xA;{LibraryNames='xxx',Folders='xxx',UserNames='xxx',RoleDefinitionNames='xxx'}&#xD;&#xA;{LibraryNames='yyy',Folders='yyy',UserNames='yyy',RoleDefinitionNames='yyy'}&#xD;&#xA;{LibraryNames='zzz',Folders='zzz',UserNames='zzz',RoleDefinitionNames='zzz'}" />
```

Notice that the file, since it is an XML, encodes the break lines as `&#xD;&#xA;` and put all the string in one line.

I would like to know if there is a way I can publish the App.config without messing the line breaks.

Or, Is it possible to keep the string value in other file? so the App.config can read the value from the file without messing with the format

Comment: Of course there is. `<add key="rightsTable" value="filename.xml">`, then you'll have to process that file at run-time.

Comment: Then, from what i understand, i would have to load the "filename.xml" file, lets say in a XmlDocument, and read the content? Unfortunately I would have to change part of the code that reads these values, which would be even more troublesome.

Comment: Note from here - https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/1057 - The JSON grammar does not allow for multi-line strings*. The VS behavior is driven from this, since it would not be possible syntactically for the next line to be part of the string token. *See https://www.json.org/ especially the part defining string tokens where it excludes control characters.

Comment: @HassanVoyeau oh, I see. That is unfortunate. I guess then this approach was not the best to store these values; reading them from a separated text file would have been better. I would have to check if is there is time to make a change like that because it could turn out troublesome. Anyway, thank you very much for your assistance. I will leave this question open in case other ideas arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jwdonahue suggested, when having large text values which need multiple lines, is better to save it in an external file and then load it using the path of the file, which is saved in the config file. I set this as the answer in order to leave this question closed.